# Can humans use time dilation in order create a tactical advantage?

Tags: gravity, time

Imagine an android being controlled with lightspeed communication. The pilot is fighting local units who are in a gravity well. The local fighters are not better trained.

Would the android seem to have super-human ability because the controller would be experiencing the fighting at a slower speed.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the (android) pilot is fighting local units, then he is local to the units he is fighting and therefore in the same gravity well. Gravitational time dilation is going to be really small for all of them, anyway, even from the vantage point of an observer outside of the well.

If the local fighters are similarly trained and have the same equipment, everyone is using lightspeed communication (i.e. radio) neither party has any real advantage.  However, the android would in fact face a significant disadvantage if it is being remotely controlled to make tactical decisions.  If the android's controller is in a spaceship with an orbit high above the melee, radio communication delays could end up being much worse than the ping speed of a multiplayer Star Wars Squadron's game between foks in Mumbai and Miami.  My money is on the local units!

Comment: FWIW, the time dilation for 1 *g* is only about 2.19 seconds per century.